# strtoull for arbitrary length strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I have a program that accepts a string representing a number up to 256 bits in length, which I need to extend to 512 bits.  The string represents a number in hexadecimal.

The way it works is, I have functions for converting strings to 64-bit, 128-bit or 256-bit numbers, where the 128-bit function calls the 64-bit function twice, the 256-bit function calls the 128-bit one twice, and the 64-bit one either uses `strotull` or manually converts the string.

Values greater than 64 bits are stored in an array of 64-bit entries.

This is ugly, hard to understand and bug prone, and I want to throw it all out.  Considering that `strtoull` already handles 64-bit values nicely, I was wondering if there's some standard library that will take an arbitrary length string and convert it to an array of numbers.

This seems like a pretty basic string parsing operation, and I'm reluctant to reinvent the wheel.

---

**Note:**

Due to licensing issues (I work at a big corporation, far removed from purchasing or legal decision making), I need to use only standard libraries (GNU, Boost, STL etc...) or else it will simply take me too long to get access to the solution.

Comment: I don't get it, does the string represent a number in binary, octal or perhaps hexadecimal form? Otherwise how does calling the 64-bit function twice generate the 128bit value?

Comment: @K-ballo: good point.  The number is in hex.  I updated the question.

Comment: That doesn't seem "ugly", especially since it works.

Comment: GNU isn't a library. It's an OS (GNU (i/ˈɡnuː/)[1] is a Unix-like computer operating system developed by the GNU project). You probably meant glibc. Are you already using OpenSSL? (I ask because 128-256 bits numbers normally are used in cryptography)

Comment: @Mat: It was running for five years when somebody did something legal, but unexpected, and the whole thing broke to pieces.  It took me a whole day to debug it.  it works only if you don't break any assumptions.  Now that I have to extend it, I want to do it well.

Comment: @xanatos: you're right.  What I meant is one of the libraries supported by GNU.

Answer (score 2):

There are many libraries available for handling large numbers. The first one that came up on Google was [GMP](http://gmplib.org/). It's LGPL, so there shouldn't be any licensing issues.

```
mpz_t i;
mpz_init_set_str (i, "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef...", 16);
```